# Get page content of SharePoint online classic page

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, classic-experience

I need to get page content of a page that is in subsite. I am not sure how to go about this. The page content hyperlink which I need to get. Whats is the best way of going about it. I essentially want to get the content out and make excel table out of all the hyperlink in the page content. It is a classic page in Sharepoint Online. I have tried to use Get-PnPCLientSidePage but that only seem to work for modern page. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by "The page content hyperlink"? AFAIK we can get web parts on a page via add ?contents=1 to the current page url to view a 'web parts maintenance page' or using PowerShell CSOM: https://global-sharepoint.com/pnp-powershell/verified-get-all-webparts-from-pages-in-a-site-using-powershell-in-sharepoint-online/ . Also, we can get web part properties using Powershell. Not sure about what page content hyperlink means. If you want to get all the hyperlinks within web parts on a page, i'm afraid it it impossible. Sorry for that if I misunderstood.

Comment: Hi Allen, thank you I really appreciate you taking time out to reply to my post :) I was able to extract the info I needed using the view.